# Use $this argument for toString method in parent in PHP

Tags: php, object, this

I want for test use a method toString() with $this argument, for just one call in all my object.
For this i have :

```
class A {
    public function toString($object) {
         $result = '<pre>';
         foreach ($object as $key => $value) {
            $result .= $key . ': ' . $value . '<br>';
         }
         $result .= '</pre>';
         return $result;
     }
}

class B extends A {
    public function toString() {
        parent::toString($this);
    }
}
```

But this throw me a :

> Strict standards: Declaration of B::toString() should be compatible with A::toString($object)

But when i use function in B with $this argument, $this is not allowed, and with other, the argument is missing.

Comment: The idea of passing an object to `toString()` in class A just sounds wrong.  You should have a `toString()` method on the object itself and not do it the way your trying (i.e. passing the object itself around).

Comment: If you feel the need to go this route your best option might be to change `A::toString($object)` to being a protected method called something like `_toString($object)` and then have `B::toString() { parent::_toString($this); }`

Comment: As a total aside - there are many built-in methods that accomplish something similar to your loop in `toString` (which, will only not handle deep objects).  Consider checking out some of them, you may find something that works: json_encode, var_export, serialize come to mind - I'm sure there's others.

Comment: ...not to mention there's already a `__toString()` magic method specifically for this kind of thing which allows you to `echo $object`

Comment: The echo $object show me error 
"Catchable fatal error: Object of class could not be converted to string"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change the definition of the method declared in the parent:

```
class B extends A {
    public function toString($object = array()) {
        parent::toString($this);
    }
}
```

EDIT: Add a default parameter to parent function

```
Class A {
    public function toString($object = array()) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I have try, but i need a $object variable for nothing

Answer (score 0):

I would change original code like this:

```
class A {
    public function toString($object = null) {
        if ($object == null) {
            return '';
        }

        $result = '<pre>';
        foreach ($object as $key => $value) {
            $result .= $key . ': ' . $value . '<br>';
        }
        $result .= '</pre>';
        return $result;
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public function toString($object = null) {
        if ($object == null) {
            $object = $this;
        }
        parent::toString($object);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If this behavior is really only going to be used by the A class on *itself* (and its children), then I'd say use PHP's magic method `__toString()` that is inherently available for any class instance.

```
class A {
    public $foo = 'foo'; // so we can see something from A in output
    public function __toString() {
        $result = '<pre>';
        foreach($this as $key => $value) {
            $result .= "$key: $value<br>";
        }
        $result .= '</pre>';
        return $result;
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public $bar = 'bar'; // so we can see something from B in output
    // nothing else to do here, really
}

$b = new B();
echo $b;
```